# Get youtube link title in post title

Tags: links, title, youtube

If my post title is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJmMiZH3Q6I`
I want it to be converted to original video title which is "Ras Cricket - Fyah"

Is there a way without API stuff cause it seems hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code into your `functions.php` file.

```
function change_title_yt( $post_id ) {
    $current_title = $_POST['post_title'];

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($current_title);

    $title_div = $doc->getElementById('eow-title');
    $title = $title_div->nodeValue;

    $my_args = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $title
    );

    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'change_title_yt');

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( $my_args );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'change_title_yt');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'change_title_yt');
```